# Minecraft keeps crashing with Shaders

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ever since I found out how to install mods, I wanted to have Shaders, more specifically RudoPlays Shaders. But every time I install shaders core mod and go to select which shader pack I want to use in Minecraft, I loads for a few seconds then my Minecraft crashes. This doesn't only happen with Rudoplays, it happens with EVERY SHADERPACK I use. I use a Windows 8 laptop, if that helps.

Here's the crash log:

```
WARNING: 0:2113: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2113: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2115: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2115: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2116: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2116: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:2116: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2116: 'mask' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2116: 'clouds' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 

...

WARNING: 0:2120: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float

WARNING: 0:2144: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2145: 'scatteredUpLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2145: 'ao' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2145: 'scatteredUpLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2146: 'scatteredUpLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2146: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:2146: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2149: 'heldLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2149: 'heldLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2149: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2150: 'heldLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2150: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'varying 3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2151: 'heldLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2151: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:2158: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:2158: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2159: 'sunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2159: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2159: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2160: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2160: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2161: 'bouncedSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2161: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2162: 'scatteredSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2162: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2163: 'nolight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2163: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2164: 'scatteredUpLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2164: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2167: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2167: 'rgb' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2167: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2167: 'rgb' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2167: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2167: 'rgb' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2167: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2167: 'pow' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2167: 'mask' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2167: 'fire' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2167: 'mix' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2171: 'final' : undeclared identifier 
ERROR: 0:2171: 'nolight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2171: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2171: 'nolight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2172: 'sunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2172: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2172: 'sunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2173: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2173: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2173: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2174: 'bouncedSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2174: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2174: 'bouncedSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2175: 'scatteredSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2175: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2175: 'scatteredSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2176: 'scatteredUpLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2176: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2176: 'scatteredUpLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2177: 'torchlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2177: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2177: 'torchlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2178: 'underwater' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2178: 'water' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2178: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2178: 'assign' :  cannot convert from '3-component vector of float' to 'float'
ERROR: 0:2181: 'underwater' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2181: 'sunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2181: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2181: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2181: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2181: 'torchlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2181: 'nolight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2181: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2185: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2185: 'lava' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2185: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2185: 'mask' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2185: 'lava' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2185: 'Glowmap' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2187: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2187: 'glowstone' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2187: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2187: 'mask' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2187: 'glowstone' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2187: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2187: 'Glowmap' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2189: 'torchlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2189: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2189: 'mask' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2189: 'glowstone' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2191: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2191: 'fire' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2191: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2191: 'mask' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2191: 'fire' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2192: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2192: 'fire' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2192: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2192: 'fire' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2192: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2192: 'pow' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2201: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2201: 'torch' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2201: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2201: 'mask' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2201: 'torch' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2201: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2201: 'pow' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2206: 'torchlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2206: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2206: 'mask' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2206: 'lava' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2208: 'heldLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2208: 'heldLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2208: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2212: 'sunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2212: 'DoNightEye' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2213: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2213: 'DoNightEye' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2214: 'bouncedSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2214: 'DoNightEye' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2215: 'scatteredSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2215: 'DoNightEye' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2216: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2216: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2216: 'DoNightEye' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2217: 'underwater' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2217: 'DoNightEye' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2219: 'nolight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2219: 'DoLowlightEye' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2221: 'cloudShadow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2221: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:2222: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2225: 'sunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2225: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2226: 'skylight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2226: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2227: 'nolight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2227: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2228: 'bouncedSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2228: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2229: 'scatteredSunlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2229: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:2229: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2230: 'scatteredUpLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2230: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2231: 'torchlight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2231: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2232: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2232: 'lava' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2232: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2233: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2233: 'glowstone' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2233: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2234: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2234: 'fire' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2234: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2235: 'glow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2235: 'torch' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2235: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2236: 'heldLight' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2236: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2225: '=' :  cannot convert from 'float' to '3-component vector of float'
ERROR: 0:2241: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2241: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
WARNING: 0:2241: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
ERROR: 0:2242: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'tintColor' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'sunglow' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2242: 'sunSpot' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2245: 'sky' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2245: 'albedo' :  field selection requires structure, vector, or matrix on left hand side 
ERROR: 0:2250: 'CalculateUnderwaterFog' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 
ERROR: 0:2254: 'CalculateAtmosphericScattering' : no matching overloaded function found (using implicit conversion) 

WARNING: 0:193: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float

...

WARNING: 0:235: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float


gcolor mipmap enabled for /shaders/composite1.fsh
composite mipmap enabled for /shaders/composite1.fsh
[SMC INF]Info log: /shaders/composite1.fsh
WARNING: 0:17: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float

...

WARNING: 0:653: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float

An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x2d480147, pid=3344, tid=13084
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig7icd32.dll+0x3a0147]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Lol\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid3344.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not close
```

Answer (score -1):

**You should send this crash report to the mod creator**

For most shaders mod you need an updated graphic card.

I would recommend that you update your graphics card and send the crash report to the mod author.

Comment: I do have an updated graphic card

Answer (score -1):

Interfering mods or simply not deleting META-INF can cause crashes.

Comment: This is a very general solution...

Comment: I dont have META-INF anywhere, I cant find it, I cant find the whole "bin" folder altogether